# Обособить несогласованное определение?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

§ 53. Несогласованные определения, выраженные существительными в форме косвенных падежей с предлогами и относящиеся к нарицательным именам существительным, обособляются:
1)  если определяемое слово уже имеет впереди стоящие согласованные определения:

Дверь отворяется, и в комнату входит маленький, сухой старик, с острой, седой бородкой.

Но, с другой стороны, на правило с уточняющими членами пишется: Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматичным, почти заспанным, лицом.

Разве по этому же правилу несогласованное определение не должно обособляться:

Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек, с флегматичным, почти заспанным, лицом.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно обособление несогласованных определений зависит от того, вкладывает ли автор значение дополнительного признака предмета в несогласованное определение. От пунктуации  зависит смысл  , например: Величественно вошла мать , в сиреневом платье, в кружевах. (акцент на величественности,величественность придают кружева и сиреневое платье, это дополнит. признак)Величественно вошла мать в сиреневом платье, в кружевах.  - несогласованное определение относится по смыслу скорее к сказуемому, чем к подлежащему:мать вошла в сиреневом платье и в кружевах, т. е. акцент на сиреневое платье и кружевах, а не на величественности.

Дверь отворяется, и в комнату входит маленький, сухой старик, с острой, седой бородкой.- обособлено потому, что "с острой, седой бородкой" - дополнительный признак сухого старика, к тому же перед определяемым словом есть согласованные определения, выражающие основные признаки.

Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматичным, почти заспанным, лицом.- флегматичное, почти заспанное лицо - основной признак человечка, а не дополнительный, дополнительный как раз то , что он небольшой и плотненький, а акцент на выражении  лица.
http://www.tutoronline.ru/blog/obosoblenie-nesoglasovannyh-opredelenij.aspx